# Using javascript framework from script tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm-scripts

I'm new in vue.js and javascript frameworks.

I have an example here based on this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-semantic-modal)

```
import modal from 'vue-semantic-modal'

export default {
   components: {
      modal
   }
}
```

But I'm more comfortable in using the script file like this.

```
<script src="...some cdn link"></script>
```

So I have no idea how to use it inside my script

```
<script>
    // don't know how to call the vue-semantic-modal
</script>
```

Comment: Using jquery https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: yes, well we all started it from some where. Earlier in the begging I also don't like  import or require concept but once you understand it then you appreciate why we use "import" , I higly encourage you to learn webpack, es6 to compile this scripts it will be very useful in future :).

Comment: I'm working with asp.net core where I normally put all of my script files inside the shared layout page that is why I need to use the global script in my project. :)

Comment: hmm, then  you should have to make your component by your self use this docu https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html and take semantic-ui stand alone modal code https://github.com/Semantic-Org/UI-Modal/blob/master/modal.js and wrap in to vue js component then you can use it like as you wanted.. ( or search some body already did that) and use .. this its the way you can use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use ES6 code like your example,

1. Add vue.js and other dependencies from [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/)
2. Add dependencies for using [Traceur compiler](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler)
3. Add your code between `<script type='module'>// code</script>` tags,more will be found [here](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Getting-Started):

Comment: Hello. I already added the script and to be rendered above. My only problem is, how can I call the package and not use the import and export script

Comment: "how can I call the package and not use the import and export script" -- npm  packages are designed to be used in this manner, not with script tags.  Are you using Node?  If you are, then you should learn about the module pattern.

Comment: I'm working with asp.net core where I normally put all of my script files inside the shared layout page.